# C# .NET Core Discord Music Bot

Tags: c#, .net-core, discord, discord.net

so I'm looking to code in some music functionality to a bot that I'm making. I've tried a whole bunch of different search terms but can't seem to come up with anything.
I'm writing the bot in C# .NET Core

I've got the basics down. Connects to a voice channel etc. But I'm not sure how to interface it with YouTube/Spotify so that it could search for url's or song titles.

So for example I'd like to be able to give it a link like this (either youtube or spotify):
[image: spotify link]

Or be able to search Youtube (or both) for a song title:
[image: play by Song title]

I'm sure there's some kind of library to download or a NuGet package or API that I can integrate, but I just can't seem to find the right search terms to use to find any tutorials or documentation on the topic.

Any help in this area would be appreciated

Comment: If you still need help see your DM on Discord.

Answer (score 2):

Well I have been in your shoes and the best solution is to abandon all native ffmpeg and all and just use `Sharplink`. It uses `lavalink` to send audio to discord without actually connecting to it.

```
DiscordSocketClient client = new DiscordSocketClient();
LavalinkManager lavalinkManager = new LavalinkManager(client, new LavalinkManagerConfig
{
    RESTHost = "localhost",
    RESTPort = 2333,
    WebSocketHost = "localhost",
    WebSocketPort = 2333,
    Authorization = "YOUR_SECRET_AUTHORIZATION_KEY",
    TotalShards = 1 
});
```

This is how you would get started. 
Once a `LavalinkManager` is set up it will need to be started. It is recommended you put this in the ready event.

```
client.Ready += async () =>
{
    await lavalinkManager.StartAsync();
}
```

Real the docs at https://github.com/Devoxin/SharpLink 
Good Luck

**EDIT: **
I made my music bot public so https://github.com/rishav394/Dota-Geek/ here it is. Look out for the music section.

Comment: Ok thanks :)
Much appreciated and will try this out. I've had a couple of other people suggest lavalink with victoria. So I'll definitely use your code as a starting point. I've moved on to some more pressing admin utilities at the moment, but I'll get back to you when I test this

Comment: @JackMcCall Sure :)